# want enable number and '&' symbol in number and punctation keyboard type

Tags: iphone, ios, uikeyboard

i am trying to enable only number and   & symbol , i am using below code but it is not working i don't know what is problem,any other way to enable only number and some symbol in key board ,please help me out with this.

thanks in advance

```
(BOOL)keyboardInput:(id)k shouldInsertText:(id)i isMarkedText:(int)b {
char s=[i characterAtIndex:0];
if(textfield1.tag == 1)
{
    if(s>=48 && s<=57 && s == 38)  // 48 to 57 are the numbers and 38 is the '&' symbol
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }

}
return YES;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if((s>=48 && s<=57) || s == 38)
```